# How to ignore favicon.ico route on ServiceStack host (non MVC)

Tags: servicestack

I'm having this weird problem with ServiceStack. I've hosted this as a regular ASP.NET web application - so no MVC project. When I browse to the metadata page I get following in my NLOG table:

```
<ipaddress> Request not found: /favicon.ico
```

How can I solve this?